# How is it correct? like vs do like

Tags: do-support, responses

- Did you play tennis? - Yes, I played.
- Did you play tennis? - Yes, I did.

Which one is correct? Both seem fine to me. But answer is saying that second one is correct.

Comment: Yes, second one is correct because in this type of ["short answers"](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/short-answers) the verb of the question is echoed in the answer by  the appropriate auxiliary.

Comment: Also, the title is *like* vs. *do like*, but your question is about playing tennis. Perhaps, you are confusing yourself. ;-)

Comment: Because I like playing tennis. ;)

Comment: The second example is a shortened form of "Yes, I did [play tennis]."  You can omit the verb phrase *play tennis* because 1) an auxiliary is present (*do*) and 2) it's recoverable from context.  Why *do*?  Because you don't have an auxiliary and you need one, and when that's the case, *do* is the one you insert: "Yes, I played tennis." -> "Yes, I did [play tennis]."  But this omission is licensed by any auxiliary, not just *do*: "Would you like some cake?  Yes, I would [like some cake]."

Answer (score 2):

*"Yes, I played"* is ungrammatical, because *play* is used transitively in the question. If you want to repeat the word *play*, answer *"Did you play tennis?"* with *"Yes, I played it.*"

Here are possible long and short answers for your question.

> Did you play tennis? - Yes, I played it.
>   Did you play tennis? - Yes, I did.

Comment: what do you mean by "transitively" here?

Comment: It (being used transitively) means that the verb needs a direct object. Compare: *I sleep.* (*sleep* here is used intransitively), *I ate it.* (*ate* here is used transitively).

Comment: This may be true in a technical sense (thus explaining the answer given in the book), but I don't think this "rule" necessarily holds in conversation. If I told my daughters to play tennis on a Saturday, and then that evening I asked them, "Did you play tennis today?" they might respond with, "Yes, we played," and I wouldn't correct their speech.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed. I often found myself saying similar phrases in chat rooms too.

Comment: It's fine.  People say things like "Oh, do you play [tennis]?"  You can analyze it as ellipsis or say it's intransitive, but theory aside, people say it and accept it so it's probably fine.